# Transparent Coffee Cup with Color Volume Makes Strange Objects

Tags: transparency

I'm following the Blender Guru beginners tutorial, and as I was making the coffee in the cup, it looked alright until you look at it from the side, where you see that it has all of these weird particles.

How do I get rid of these?
[Blend File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/03m7m9mzlbc3jgm/donut1.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Please use this tool to upload your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - More importantly, can you post an image of the particles you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There is a known blender issue with "liquids" in cups. Make sure the liquid mesh fully intersects the glass (as in the boundry of the mesh is inside the glass wall, not inside the empty space)

[image]